# Resource Exhausted in Tensorflow with any architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I tried to train a image classifier using tensorflow. I used data api to load the dataset and i used dataset caching to speed up training process. while trying to training the model i struck with a error called Resource Exhausted. I tried to change the batch size even after trying different batch size like 32,64,128 i could not over come this problem
[image]

I have tried to remove some layers but i could not fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your batch_size. Decrease it. It seems it is overwhelming.